User is a group is not receiving emails
We use Gmail with Workspaces, or G-Suite or whatever it's called. We have a group, say info@abc.com. Some of our members and aliases in that group are not receiving emails and I have no idea why. After looking at things in google's "Admin" app, under that info@abc.com group, I see this column "Relation" which has 2 type of values: "Direct" and "Direct and Indirect".

So far it seems to have a consistent pattern:

Emails with "Direct and Indirect" value receive emails.
Emails with "Direct" value do not receive emails.

I suspect this could be a problem (maybe, maybe not). I want to try changing "Direct" value on that first row and see if that email address will start receiving emails. However, I have no idea where to change that value. I could not find any information on this on internet whatsoever.
Questions:

How can I change the value of this "Relation" column from "Direct" to "Direct and Indirect"?

Alternatively, if this is not the problem, what else can I check to make all of the emails and aliases/groups inside the group to receive emails?


